# Java Saxon lib error when extracting data from html 4.0 file

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, saxon

I have diff report in html format of two directories( with xml files)

I need to extra the desired data from this report. I wrote a simple xslt and tried this:

```
 java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:diff.xsl -s:Diff\ Report.html
```

This ends with

```
 SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must
  end with '>'.
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported
```

Html file header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> ....
```

XSLT:(very basic it does nothing)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  version="2.0"  exclude-result-prefixes="html">
<xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
   <translations>      
        <xsl:apply-templates />     
  </translations>           
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The question is , is it possible to parse html 4.0 documents with this lib ? Or I have to add some namespaced or modify the source document to fix this error ?

Comment: Saxon is an XSLT processor and uses the underlying XML parser to build its tree structure. So normally the input must be well-formed XML. You can however nominate an HTML parser like TagSoup to be used instead of an XML parser with the option `-x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser`. You will need to make sure TagSoup is on the class path.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I think that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: thanks @MartinHonnen I tidied the html using -asxhtml and it seems to be behaving .

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, copying @MartinHonnen's response as an answer:

Saxon is an XSLT processor and uses the underlying XML parser to build its tree structure. So normally the input must be well-formed XML. You can however nominate an HTML parser like TagSoup to be used instead of an XML parser with the option -x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser. You will need to make sure TagSoup is on the class path.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the `TagSoup` idea ,I did not know that . Instead I used the saxon parser but before that I passed the html file through `tidy` to generate `xhtml` and updated `DOCTYPE` that worked perfectly